# Image Files Loading Locally But Not Online?

Tags: html, image

I have a stupidly simple problem and I cannot solve it. All I want to do is to pull files from my local disk (where the website is being hosted) but the file paths are not being recognized or something. I tried a whole bunch of variations:

```
<img class="img-polaroid" src="groceries.jpg" />
<img class="img-polaroid" src="C:/path/to/file/groceries.jpg" />
<img class="img-polaroid" src="file:///C/path/to/file/groceries.jpg" />
```

What are my options for loading local images? How can I separately "host" images so I can reference them with a URL or something? Which is better?

Comment: I'm actually using node.js to serve a single html file. How do I get it to serve my images so I can reference them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't, because think of it, it'll be a security risk. Your friend would send you and HTML file, and there it is, it accesses all the files on your C drive and deletes them.

However, you can `serve` files (including image files) locally.

All you need is to install a local web server, and host your site in that server, and change the DNS settings, so that user would access a locally installed website using names in the browser, just the way they surf the Internet.

Comment: I'm using node.js to serve my webpage on port 8080, any links to how I can get it to serve a whole directory?

Comment: If you are using express something like:     `app.use(express.static(path.normalize('path/to/your/image/dir')));`

Answer (score 1):

You can provide images from your machine if it's reachable from the outside (the Internet). If it is, just provide a link to your computer.

It is not advisable to use your local machine (maybe just for some show-off purposes).

You can:

1. Place images on the server:

   and specify paths as:

   - relative to URL: `src="path/to/file"`. Notice there is no `/` at the beginning of the path. This way, if the page is at URL `www.example.com/something`, the URL for the resource becomes `www.example.com/something/path/to/file`.
   - absolute to URL: `src="/path/to/file"`. Notice the `/` at the beginning of the path. This way, if the page is at URL `www.example.com/something`, the URL for the resource becomes `www.example.com/path/to/file`.
2. Use a [cdn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network):

   - provide src as `src="<cdn URL>/path/to/image"`